# Running android avdmanager with sudo

Tags: linux, command-line, android, environment-variables, sudo

I am running `avdmanager create avd` from my python script that I start with `sudo -E` to make my script be able to do priveldged stuff. But for some reason avdmanager created AVD inside `/root/.android/avd`, but not inside `/home/user/.android/avd`. How does it know that it is being run with sudo? I am really confused.

I've figured out that the problem is not caused by python itself. Because when I run in terminal `sudo -E avdmanager create avd` the problem remains.
Please, help me to come up with solution.

**EDIT:**

As Kamil Maciorowski advised, I checked an output of `sudo -E env | grep -E '^HOME=|^USER='` and here it is:

```
HOME=/home/username
USER=root
```

Then I tried to re-run my command as follows: `sudo --preserve-env=USER,HOME avdmanager create avd`, because with this prefix `sudo --preserve-env=USER,HOME env | grep -E '^HOME=|^USER='` what I expect:

```
USER=username
HOME=/home/username
```

but it doesn't work as well.

**EDIT 2:**

Preserving `LOGNAME` doesn't resolve the issue too. And there is no variables left from `printenv` output that contain any reference to my user.

Comment: In general a process may notice its parent is `sudo`; or it may notice `SUDO_USER` in the environment. But here it's enough that `avdmanager` notices it's being run as root (because of `sudo` or not, irrelevant); it may check `USER` in the environment or run an equivalent of `whoami`. If the purpose of `sudo -E` is to keep `HOME` of the invoking user, it's a sane approach, but (1) I guess `sudoers` policy may interfere or (2) `avdmanager` may ignore or re-initiate `HOME`. What is the output of `sudo -E env | grep -E '^HOME=|^USER='`? Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for the explanation. I've edited the question.

Comment: To avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310), please explain what "be able to do priveldged stuff" means exactly.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think it doesn't matter. I mentioned it just for an additional context. I need to my python script be able to edit files that I can't edit without root priveledges. The problem is that `avdmanager` somehow knows that I run it with sudo and as I found out it is not the problem of python (I've explained it in my question body)

Comment: Formal note: there's the [revision history](https://superuser.com/posts/1780670/revisions). Users familiar with your post can check it to see what has changed. For first-time viewers these "EDIT" headlines in the body of the question are nothing but noise. Often it's better to add new information where it fits, not necessarily at the end. I'm not saying you should rebuild the question. I'm saying you don't need to emphasize edits, the site tracks changes anyway.

Comment: Cross-posted from Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251354/44325